# Converting a date in MySQL from string field

Tags: mysql, date

I'm using a system where the dates are stored as strings in the format `dd/mm/yyyy`. Is it possible to convert this to `yyyy-mm-dd` in a SELECT query (so that I can use `DATE_FORMAT` on it)? Does MySQL have a date parsing function?

Currently the only method I can think of is to concatenate a bunch of substrings, but hopefully there's a simpler solution.

(Unfortunately I can't convert the field to a true date field since it's a meta-table: the same column contains values for different fields that are just strings.)

Answer (score 130, accepted):

This:

```
STR_TO_DATE(t.datestring, '%d/%m/%Y')
```

...will convert the string into a datetime datatype.  To be sure that it comes out in the format you desire, use [DATE_FORMAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format):

```
DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(t.datestring, '%d/%m/%Y'), '%Y-%m-%d')
```

If you can't change the datatype on the original column, I suggest [creating a view](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-view.html) that uses the `STR_TO_DATE` call to convert the string to a DateTime data type.

Comment: its helpful and helped me a lot for a quick solution

Comment: Good to mention DATE_FORMAT if the column is already in Date format.

Answer (score 17):

Yes, there's [str_to_date](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date)

```
mysql> select str_to_date("03/02/2009","%d/%m/%Y");
+--------------------------------------+
| str_to_date("03/02/2009","%d/%m/%Y") |
+--------------------------------------+
| 2009-02-03                           |
+--------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 4):

[STR_TO_DATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) allows you to do this, and it has a format argument.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE(dateString, '%d/%m/%y') FROM yourTable...
```