# Repeating functions in a MySQL query

Tags: mysql, optimization

Based on [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1861489/converting-a-date-in-mysql-from-string-field) I am running a query like so:

```
SELECT DISTINCT DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(`value`, '%d/%m/%Y'), '%M %Y') AS `avail`
FROM table
ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(`value`, '%d/%m/%Y')
```

The`value` field is in the format *dd/mm/yyyy* and using `STR_TO_DATE` I convert it to *yyyy-mm-dd*. However I repeat that function call twice, so I was wondering (a) how efficient it is, and (b) if so, how to improve efficiency (and readability)?

I know in this case it's probably a micro-optimization but I'm interested anyway - there are surely more complex functions where an optimization would make a significant difference.

Comment: I believe this is not your *actual* query (`... ORDER BY order by ...`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the mysql query optimizer should take care of this.

mysql would allow using aliases in the group by clause, but every other DBMS does not