# Get records from the current data

Tags: php, mysql

I need to list the records from the current day, in the db the date is in format 02/02/11

Database

```
09/01/11
13/01/11
18/02/11
19/02/11
20/02/11
```

...

Question:
How to do using SQL command + PHP?

Current (working...)

```
$today = date("Y/m/d");

$sql = SELECT * FROM places WHERE STR_TO_DATE(data, '%d/%m/%y') >= '".$today."' ORDER BY DATE_FORMAT(data, '%d/%m/%y') ASC LIMIT 8";
```

But all records are listed

Comment: Is this a MySql `DATE` field or something else?

Comment: it's a MySql TEXT field, all data was imported from a spreadsheet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would strongly recommend updating your stored values to the standard MySQL date field type - this will greatly simplify any queries you write and enable you to use all the standard MySQL date and time functions.

You can follow the answer here [Converting a date in MySQL from string field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1861489/converting-a-date-in-mysql-from-string-field) to find out how to convert your data.