# convert the existing data varchar and column into a DATE

Tags: mysql, sql

I stored date as a
varchar(256)    latin1_swedish_ci

which shows up as:  11/22/2012

Now I wanted to convert the existing data and column to a DATE

What would be the easiest way to do this in SQL

thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To be on the safe side I personally would add a new column, Transfer the data and then delete

```
update `table` set `new_col` = str_to_date( `old_col`, '%m/%d/%Y' ) ;
```

Check the data is OK before you delete the column.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit** to convert the existing data use:

```
STR_TO_DATE(t.datestring, '%d/%m/%Y')
```

Source: [Convert String to Date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1861489/converting-a-date-in-mysql-from-string-field)

You may need to create a temp table to hold your data for conversion:

```
CREATE [TEMPORARY] TABLE [IF NOT EXISTS] tbl_name
    (create_definition,...)
    [table_options]
    [partition_options]
```

Then you can truncate the table:

```
TRUNCATE [TABLE] tbl_name
```

Then you can alter the column datatype:

```
ALTER TABLE tablename MODIFY columnname DATE;
```

Then you can reload from the temp table:

```
INSERT INTO table 
  SELECT temptable.column1, temptable.column2 ... temptable.columnN
  FROM temptable;
```

Comment: Will it actually convert these strings to the correct date? I don't think `mm/dd/yyyy` is the date format MySQL will parse.

Comment: No, the initial SQL just changed the table data type. The data will need to be temproarily moved, converted, the column datatype updated, and the data moved back.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `STR_TO_DATE` function.

Make a new column that is the correct datatype, move the strings from the old column into the new one with the `STR_TO_DATE` function, and then delete the old column.

`UPDATE table SET new_col = STR_TO_DATE(old_col);`

[MySQL STR_TO_DATE Reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date).