# MySQL search between dates

Tags: mysql

I have a field in my table that holds the registration date in the following format

26 August 2013, 5:48:17 AM

Which is the best way to search between dates in this format?

Comment: You should use the correct data type for storage to begin with, for example DATETIME or TIMESTAMP

Comment: possible duplicate of [Converting a date in MySQL from string field](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1861489/converting-a-date-in-mysql-from-string-field)

Answer (score 0):

Just use BETWEEN

```
SELECT 
  *
FROM
  table1
WHERE
  date BETWEEN Curdate() 
  AND Curdate() - INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

Pay attention, the borders get included.
It also works on timestamps.