# ORDER BY bad format date column

Tags: mysql, date, format

How can I order by this (in column **date**) - not so good - date format.

```
7 Dec 2013 - 5 Feb 2014
31 Oct 2013 - 29 Dec 2013
3 Dec 2013 - 31 Jan 2014
3 Dec 2013 - 31 Jan 2014
```

I only need to sort by the first date, which will be

```
7 Dec 2013
31 Oct 2013
3 Dec 2013
3 Dec 2013
```

I have checked STR_TO_DATE, but if Im not wrong I need to have a string to put in to this, which I dont have. Every date is in the database column **date**.

Comment: Filipe Silva it is a string (varchar). Veelen I dont now how to approach this so I haven't started yet, thats why I ask here.

Comment: Keeping date as string is very bad, you should rework and put two date columns, it will be way more efficient and convenient for future.

Comment: Agree with @AlexandreLavoie. See this post on how to do this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1861489/converting-a-date-in-mysql-from-string-field

Comment: The solution from Filipe Silva could be useful as a start to create two new columns.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM tab1
ORDER BY str_to_date(left(col1,INSTR(col1,' -')), '%d %M %Y')
```

This gets the string to the left of `' -'`, then converts it to date format of day month year and sorts it as a date.

<kbd>[sqlfiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9df3e/2)</kbd>

p.s. I agree with the previous comments, that this would easily avoided if you used two columns for start_date and end_date of each period. And it would be faster also.