# Group by month in the date field (string)

Tags: php, codeigniter, activerecord

A table with a string field where date is being stored (don't suggest me to change the field type. It will cause hazard).

```
+--+----------+------+
|id|date      |amount|
+--+----------+------+
|1 |23-03-2014|5000  |
+--+----------+------+
|2 |25-03-2014|3000  |
+--+----------+------+
|3 |21-04-2014|3000  |
+--+----------+------+
|4 |25-04-2014|4000  |
+--+----------+------+
```

I want to write a model function which will return sum of amount grouped by month from the table. How should I do it? It will show output like

```
03 - 8000
04 - 7000
```

Comment: Is this work for you? http://stackoverflow.com/a/508806/685060

Comment: I think not, cause my date field is string type and changing this will cause me a lot of work

Comment: no, amount is integer type

Comment: I think you should try it first.

Comment: date is string so mysql date like MONTH() function won't work. As you insisted I tried. But it shouldn't and hasn't worked

Comment: is your data stored in a contineous format (ie) in the order of dates

Comment: NO, they are parsed from a csv file as plain string

Comment: so you mean that they could be shuffled

Comment: convert string type to date http://stackoverflow.com/a/1861551/685060

Comment: are you interested in converting and updating the 'string date' as date or you just want to group them for your desired result??

Comment: just want to group them for desired result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT MONTH(date_field) as mon, SUM(amount) as total FROM table_name GROUP BY MONTH(date_field);
```

Update:

```
SELECT SUBSTR(date_field,6,2) as mon, SUM(amount) as total FROM table_name GROUP BY mon;
```

Comment: Sorry this doesn't work as I mentioned earlier that date is a string field.

Comment: @Alvi_1987 Edited. If it has helped then can you please accept my answer?

Answer (score 0):

You can try following query

```
SELECT SUM(amount) FROM table GROUP BY MONTH(date)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [MONTH()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_month)

```
SELECT MONTH(date),SUM(amount) FROM table GROUP BY MONTH(date)
```