# MySQL date conversion(“01/Jan/2015” to “01012015”)

Tags: php, mysql, date

I have date format in MySQL date (varchar) column: "01/Jan/2015". I want to convert it to "01012015" format.

Is this possible in MySQL date format?

Comment: if using mysql , this should be the question to look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1861489/converting-a-date-in-mysql-from-string-field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you need to use `str_to_date` function

```
select str_to_date("01/Jan/2015","%d/%b/%Y");
```

This will convert your varchar date to real date and up on it you need to apply `date_format` function as

```
select date_format(str_to_date("01/Jan/2015","%d/%b/%Y"),"%m%d%Y");


mysql> select date_format(str_to_date("01/Jan/2015","%d/%b/%Y"),"%m%d%Y") as date;
+----------+
| date     |
+----------+
| 01012015 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

All you need to replace the hard-coded date in the above query with the column name as

```
select date_format(str_to_date(CDATE,"%d/%b/%Y"),"%m%d%Y");
```

Comment: Thanks its working fine only for 01/Jan/2015. I want to use column name in place of 01/Jan/2015. The column name is CDATE. Can you help me please?

Comment: Yes all the date is showing but not maintaining order. Can you see the output please in this link [output](http://prntscr.com/6i7hg7)

Comment: Just add `order by (str_to_date(CDATE,"%d/%b/%Y"),"%m%d%Y")` at the end of the query.

Comment: It gives me `01012015`, `01022015`, `01032015` so on. I want to display first all date of January like `01012015`,`02012015`,`03012015`, then February and so on.

Comment: Apologies the order by should be as `order by str_to_date(CDATE,"%d/%b/%Y")`

Answer (score 1):

You want to convert "01/Jan/2015" into "01012015":

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE('01/Jan/2015','%d/%b/%Y'), '%d%m%Y')
```

Notice that in `STR_TO_DATE` you use `%b` for the 3-letter month, but in `DATE_FORMAT` you use %m for the 2-digit month.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL retrieves and displays DATE values in 'YYYY-MM-DD' format.  You should use your application layer to reformat into the desired format.  If you are using PHP you can use the date() function to do that

Answer (score 0):

This could help you

```
strtotime($date);
```

Comment: Can you test this `PHP` function and show the code and output in your answer?

Comment: sry, actually its time function