# MySQL and PHP inserting a date into a Date field

Tags: php, mysql, date

I have a date like so: `07/15/2015` and I am trying to insert this date into a `Date` database column. My problem is with this date is that database saves the date as `0000-00-00` how do I get the date to save properly like so `2015-07-15` Here is the code I am using to insert:

```
function insertCareer($connection, $date, $title, $text){


                if($stmt = $connection->prepare("INSERT INTO `careers` (date, title, text) VALUES (?, ?, ?)")){
                        $stmt->bind_param('sss', $date, $title, $text);
                        $stmt->execute();
                        $stmt->close();
                        echo 'Career has been added <br>';
                }

        }
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: What does `$date` contain?

Comment: You can save date as YYYY-MM-DD in mysql. Not like DD-MM-YYYY !!!

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/a/1861551/689579 to do it in mysql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL does not understand the date in the format you're providing it. Considering that is ambiguous anyway (`D/M/Y` in Europe, `M/D/Y` in USA), you should always pass dates around as `Y/M/D`.

```
SELECT CAST('07/01/2015' AS DATE); -- this is null
SELECT CAST('2015/07/01' AS DATE); -- this is 2015-07-01
```

So use a something like this to make it work:

```
$date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date));
```

---

Argh, beat by 15 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the date format.

Use `date('Y-m-d', strtotime($YOUR_DATE));`

[More about strtotime()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)

[More about date()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

In your case:

```
$stmt->bind_param('sss', date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date)), $title, $text);
```

Answer (score 0):

If `$date` is not set, you can set a default value as today's date in YYYY-MM-DD format like so:

```
function insertCareer($connection, $date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime()), $title, $text){
    if($stmt = $connection->prepare("INSERT INTO `careers` (`date`, `title`, `text`) VALUES (?, ?, ?)")){
        $stmt->execute(array($date, $title, $text));
        $stmt->close();
        echo 'Career has been added <br>';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify your date as in PHP

```
$dateArray = explode ("/" ,$date);

$Format = $dateArray[2] . "/" . $dateArray[0] . "/" . $dateArray[1];
```

then

```
$stmt->bind_param('sss', CAST('$Format' AS DATE), $title, $text);
```

Answer (score 0):

MySQL support ISO-8601 date/time values (yyyy-mm-dd). I suggest to use a function to convert the date format from yyyy-mm-dd to mm/dd/yyyy. You just need to pass the date value from the database. echo DateFormat($dbDate);

```
function DateFormat($dateval){
  $newdate = date('m/d/Y', strtotime($dateval));
  return $newdate;
}
```