# SQL Finding the date difference when two formats are different

Tags: sql

I have a date stored in format like

```
18/1/2012 18:51:35
```

I have to find the difference in days between one date and current date. To get current date i am using  `getdate()` which returns the below

```
2015-10-30 10:01:25.493
```

Currently i am using `charindex` and `substring` function to make to formats equal in `datediff()`. Is there a better way

Comment: What DBMS are you using (MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle, etc)? When you say you have a date stored in that format, is it just stored as a `VARCHAR`? Ideally you would `CONVERT` the first format into an actual date type and then do the comparison with datediff without mucking around with `charindex` and `substring`.

Answer (score 0):

I think this has been answered here:

[Converting a date in MySQL from string field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1861489/converting-a-date-in-mysql-from-string-field)

where (i think) you basically would just, (haven't tested :/)

```
datediff(STR_TO_DATE(your_column_to_convert, '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S'), CURRENT_DATE())
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is the MSSQL code which you are looking for.

```
DECLARE @column_date VARCHAR(50)
SET @column_date = '18/1/2012 18:51:35'

SELECT DATEDIFF(DAY,CAST(CONVERT(DATETIME,@column_date,103) AS DATETIME),GETDATE())
```

Try replacing your column with @column_date.

Hope it will help you.

Comment: Please specify which dbms this is for. (Product specific answer to a question with no dbms tagged...)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you using SQL Server, as the `GETDATE()` and `CHARINDEX()` are specific to MSSQL.

If the date `18/1/2012 18:51:35` is stored in VARCHAR, you could probably use

```
DECLARE @DateFromTable VARCHAR(20)
SET @DateFromTable = '18/1/2012 18:51:35'

SELECT DATEDIFF(DAY, CONVERT(DATETIME,@DateFromTable, 103), GETDATE());
```

Refer to [Cast and Convert functions here.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx)