# SQL date/time field query

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime

I've got a database with table named tblTest, it has got a date/time field named LastDate

I'm trying to run a query:

```
update tblTest 
set lastDate= '20/02/2016'
where lastDate = '08/04/2016'
```

But it's not working, I've tried CAST('20/02/2016' AS DATE) but it doesn't seem to work either.

Can anyone advise please?

Thank you

Comment: Define "not working". Please include table structures, sample data, and expected output. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: possible duplicate from [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1861489/converting-a-date-in-mysql-from-string-field)

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
 update tblTest set lastDate= '20-02-2016' where lastDate = '08-04-2016'
```

Since you are using the datetime type it should be

```
update tblTest set lastDate= '20-02-2016 00:00:00' where lastDate = '08-04-2016 00:00:00'
```

Comment: Unfortunately when I use that it's coming up with 3464 - Data type mismatch in criteria expression, does that have something to do with time missing from the string? As the field is a date/time type.

Comment: Yes you didnt mention that. That would be it

Comment: Unfortunately it's still doing the same thing, now I'm using 'DD-MM-YYYY HH:MM:SS' format and it's doing exactly the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

If `lastDate` is of type `datetime` then this should work:

```
update tblTest 
set lastDate = '2016-02-20'
where lastDate = '2016-04-08'
```

This query uses a string literal formatted according to ANSI SQL standards.

Comment: same as below - 3464 - Data type mismatch in criteria expression

Comment: @Michal Where are you issuing the query from?

Comment: Well I'm running it from a small app that has been written for that purpose for a specific company so I'm guessing that this will be a problem. I'll try running it from somewhere else.

Comment: @Michal The query should run ok. The problem probably lies in the way you issue the sql statement from client side.

Comment: Bear in mind that if you use hyphens in that date format, it will *still* be language sensitive. e.g. try `SET LANGUAGE FRENCH` before that query and it will break because `2016-02-20` will be interpreted as the 2nd day of the 20th month. The hyphenless format, e.g. `'20160220'`, is safe for all languages.

Answer (score 0):

this has worked:

```
update tblData set LastSalesDate = #2016-03-20# where LastSalesDate = #2016-10-08#
```

Thank you everyone for your answers.
Michal