# MYSQL Date comparison issue Exception

Tags: java, mysql

I have looked at the suggestions on other questions. Have added back tics, checked that I am comparing date values, but unable to make this code work. What am I doing wrong in this statement?

`SELECT * from project where project.completed_date >= '2015-01-01' order by customer, projectName`

It gives me an exception

> "javax.servlet.ServletException: java.sql.SQLException: Unknown column '2015-01-01' in 'where clause'"

Why is it seeing that date as a column and not a value?

Comment: please do proper formatting.

Answer (score 1):

You should be using single (or double) quotes around the date, not backticks.  Hence the query should look like:

```
SELECT *
FROM project
WHERE project.completed_date >= '2015-01-01'
ORDER BY customer, projectName
```

Comment: tried using just single quote marks and not getting an error but also not getting anything returned. (SELECT * from project where project.completed_date >= '2015-01-01' order by customer, projectName)

Comment: Either you have no matching data or possibly you made `completed_date` a `varchar` column (naughty naughty).

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
SELECT *
FROM project
WHERE completed_date >= STR_TO_DATE('2015-01-01', '%Y-%m-%d')
ORDER BY customer, projectName
```

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing a string and a date. Rewrite your query like:

```
SELECT * from project where project.completed_date >= STR_TO_DATE('2015-01-01','%Y-%m-%d') order by customer, projectName
```

For more information on that see: [Converting a date in MySQL from string field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1861489/converting-a-date-in-mysql-from-string-field)

Comment: Tried this (SELECT * from project where project.completed_date >= STR_TO_DATE('2015-01-01','%Y-%m-%d') order by customer, projectName) and not getting an error but so am I not getting anything returned and there should be 100's in column that would match

Comment: what is the type of `project.completed_date` or the format ?

Comment: Ah, I used the wild-cards for Oracle database. I just corrected my answer.

Comment: When I look in Heidi it shows it is of Datatype DATE

Comment: yup that seemed to do it...   thanks... appreciate the quick responses

Comment: Vote up my answer then.