# How to change dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss to yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss using sql

Tags: mysql, sql

How to change

> dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss

to

> yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss

using in MySql

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (Many products are far from ANSI SQL compliant when it comes to date/time.)

Comment: My rdbms is MySQL

Comment: Try to use date_format : https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format

Comment: First, what is the data type of your datetime field ? String, datetime, Timestamp ??

Comment: data type is varchar

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting a date in MySQL from string field](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1861489/converting-a-date-in-mysql-from-string-field)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
  STR_TO_DATE(Column_Date,GET_FORMAT(DATE,'ISO'))
```

Comment: My column name is new_date

Comment: try this . STR_TO_DATE(new_date ,GET_FORMAT(DATE,'ISO'))

Comment: Not working 17/11/2016 05:00:16
17/11/2016 05:27:26
17/11/2016 05:46:04

Answer (score 0):

Try this

You need to use STR_TO_DATE() to convert that string into a datetime type and then use DATE_FORMAT() to format that in the new desired format:

```
DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE("<Your Date>", "%Y/%m/%d %H:%i:%s.%f"), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s")
```

Comment: My column name is new_date

Comment: replace it with <Your Date>

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @DatetimeString VARCHAR(25) = '23/10/2016  10:12:12.000'

SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(24), CONVERT(DATETIME, @DatetimeString, 103), 121) Date
```

Expected output would be

> 2011/04/14 18:11:56

Answer (score 0):

You want to convert a string of format 'dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss' to a string of format 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss'.

This is a strange request. First reason: Where does that string come from? Why isn't it of type datetime or timestamp? In a database that should be the case. You should not store datetimes as strings. Second reason: Why do you want to create such a string? Why not a datetime or timestamp?

Anyway, the function to get a substring in MySQL is (unsurprisingly) `SUBSTRING`. Strange enough you have not been able to find this out yourself. It is in the docs: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_substring.

```
new =
  substring(old, 7, 4) || 
  '-'
  substring(old, 4, 2) || 
  '-'
  substring(old, 1, 2) || 
  ||
  substring(old, 11)
```