# I want to store the value from the html5 input type = "date" element and want to store the exact same in the database

Tags: php, mysql, html, date, input

I am using the HTML5 date element

```
<input type="date" name="dob"/> <!--For example if I selected 03/04/2000-->
<input type="submit">
```

Whenever I try to retrieve the same data in the PHP document like this...

```
$dob = $_POST['dob'];
echo $dob; // This statement prints the correct output ie. 2000-03-04
//But now when I store the same in the database like
$sql = "INSERT INTO user (dob) VALUES ('$dob')";
if(mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) // I had written the connection part in my code hence $conn
echo "Inserted successfully";
else
echo "Error updating";
```

> At this point when I check my database for the results it have the value **1993**

I do not understand why does it occur... the data type I used for the column dob is **varchar** because the the date element returns a string value..

It will be really very helpful if someone helps[This are some of the ouputs that i got after different inputs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fsu4U.png)

Comment: What is the field type for your dob field in your database? I'm guessing it's not a Date field.

Comment: MYSQL expects you to set a date in the format `YYYY-MM-DD` for DATE and DATETIME and TIMESTAMP columns. If you want to see it in a different format then that is the job of your presentation layer, not the database storage mechanism

Comment: Can you check your column type? maybe is `NUMBER` or something, so mysql made a implicit conversion..

Comment: my database column type is "varchar"...plz help

Comment: Now if i change the type to date it shows the output 0000-00-00....plz help

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1861489/converting-a-date-in-mysql-from-string-field for converting a date string to a date type in MySql.

Answer (score 0):

Please format your input value like this

Use `date_format()` function in PHP.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO user (dob) VALUES ('date_format($dob,\"Y-m-d\")')";
```