# mysql date_format is not working returning empty

Tags: mysql, sql

I am having problem while getting the result i want from database, DATE_FORMAT function is returning null instead or returning a formatted date.

table columns and their datatype:

paid_amount -> float

created_at -> varchar(100)

bellow is the query is:

```
SELECT SUM(paid_amount) AS amount, 
date_format(created_at,'%Y-%m-%d') as dated 
FROM `job_card` 
WHERE date_format(created_at,'%Y-%m-%d') >= '2017-09-03' AND 
date_format(created_at,'%Y-%m-%d') <= '2017-10-03' GROUP BY date(created_at)
```

I am using another approach of converting date to time stamp using UNIX_TIMESTAMP function but the still getting the same issue:

```
SELECT SUM(paid_amount) AS paid_amount, 
UNIX_TIMESTAMP(created_at) AS duration 
FROM job_card 
WHERE UNIX_TIMESTAMP(created_at) >= 1504549800 AND 
UNIX_TIMESTAMP(created_at) <= 1507055400 GROUP BY date(payment_date)
```

Comment: Why `created_at` as varchar. It should be in date format.

Comment: So, what values are in `created_at`?

Comment: @chris85 ohh, you are right. Let me edit the post.

Comment: I would suggest converting the date from your string. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1861489/converting-a-date-in-mysql-from-string-field

Comment: `DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(created_at, '%d/%m/%Y'), '%Y-%m-%d')` will help.

Comment: created_at column contain date like: 03-09-2017 14:03:02

Comment: @Nitin: I would suggest you to change varchar to datetime data type. Rather than converting into date format and check the conditions

Comment: @NanaPartykar str_to_date is not working

Comment: @NanaPartykar, thanks allot changing datatype to DATETIME worked.

Comment: Good @NitinSoni. Know data types of database table column for more understanding.

Answer (score -1):

You can't use the date functions on a `varchar` field. You'll need to convert `created_at` to a `date` field.

That will make your SQL a lot cleaner as well as you can just use clauses like `created_at > '2017-09-03'` directly in your query.

I don't know how your dates are formatted currently as strings, but your best bet is probably to write something to read the dates out, format them as `YYYY-MM-DD`, and re-insert them. If all the dates are that format you should be able to convert that field to date type and keep the information intact.

```
mysql> desc test;
+--------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field  | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+--------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| field1 | varchar(10) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+--------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from test;
+------------+
| field1     |
+------------+
| 2017-01-01 |
+------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> alter table test modify field1 date;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.24 sec)
Records: 1  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> desc test;
+--------+------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field  | Type | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+--------+------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| field1 | date | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+--------+------+------+-----+---------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from test;
+------------+
| field1     |
+------------+
| 2017-01-01 |
+------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Thank you @USD Matt Changing datatype to DATETIME worked for me.