# SSRS issue matching date with parameters

Tags: mysql, reporting-services

I have a SSRS report using an ODBC connection with MySQL. I have a problem to match the date with the parameters. When I type a date manually in the query it works fine, no problem. But when I use the parameters, it doesn't return anything. One thing I found is that the date data returned is under the format YYYY-MM-DD and the date from parameter is DD/MM/YYYY. I tried CONVERT and STRING_TO_DATE functions of MySQL but no luck. Any clue?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Check this out - https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/827a5505-b720-4ad3-ba87-b13fff7eb7bc/reporting-services-report-parameters-and-mysql?forum=sqlreportingservices

Comment: I was able to retrieve data when the date is equal but BETWEEN or > signs  don't work.    " AND DATE_FORMAT(DON.DonDate,""%m/%e/%Y"") = '" & Parameters!DateDebut.Value & "'"

Answer (score 0):

convert the parameter value to a date based on the format sent from the SSRS to match the format you are using in the manual test.

[Converting a date in MySQL from string field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1861489/converting-a-date-in-mysql-from-string-field)