# mysql value sort by date but this column type is not a date type

Tags: php, mysql, date, sql-order-by

i have a database values values like this format

```
premium_paid_date
31-10-17
30-10-17
11-10-18
31-08-18
31-10-17
25-11-17
```

but it was stored type is var-char. my customer wants this table ORDER BY year. which mean based on last two digits and followed by month and date. how can i order this using MySQL without convert into date format

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1861489/converting-a-date-in-mysql-from-string-field

Answer (score 1):

You can convert string to date in your order by statement. Like

SELECT Premium_paid_date FROM Table_Name
ORDER BY Convert( DateTime, premium_paid_date, 102) DESC

[see date format](http://www.sqlines.com/oracle-to-sql-server/to_date)

Comment: thank you for your response i used this query "SELECT premium_paid_date FROM userlogin ORDER BY CONVERT( DateTime, `userlogin`.`premium_paid_date`, 102) DESC" but it returns an error like this "#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '`userlogin`.`premium_paid_date`) DESC LIMIT 0, 25' at line 1"

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

SELECT [premium_paid_date]
  FROM [dbo].[premium_paid_date]
  ORDER BY SUBSTRING(Date,5,6)

then you are only ordering it by the last 2 digits of the date (the year) using the substring.

Comment: i need to convert into date format then execute the query.

Comment: oh, I'm confused because in your question you said "without convert into date format" so I assumed you didn't want to convert it into a date format! you could still order them using the substring method then simply convert them into date time.  plenty of ways to skin a kangaroo.

Comment: oh sorry for my mistake.can you help me for ordering this table..no restriction for convert to date method

Answer (score 1):

Finally i solved this issue my answer is

```
SELECT * FROM `tablename` order by STR_TO_DATE(premium_paid_date, '%d-%m-%Y') desc
```