# Birthdate off by one date

Tags: javascript, sql-server

I have a javascript app in which the user selects their birthdate using a 3rd party datepicker.

This date is then sent to the server, where it is stored in SqlServer as a Date (not a DateTime, nor a DateTimeOffset).

This typically works fine.  However, if the user is in a timezone such as +2:00, and it's just after midnight, then the date which is sent to the server is now different.

For example, I select the date of Jan 1, 2000 in the DatePicker.

The value which is being sent to the server is: `1999-12-31T22:00:00.000Z`

The server then strips the time off it to store it as a date, and then the date is now off by one.

How do I resolve this?

Comment: Send only the date.

Comment: What datepicker and how are you sending the value? Provide a [mcve]

Comment: It seems like it would be helpful to know exactly what the 3rd party date picker was producing. You should be able to turn this into a simple date string you can send to the server.

Comment: How do I create a new date object that is just the date?

Comment: Using the Syncfusion DatePicker

Comment: @BrahmaDev, If you want to post your comment as an answer, I will accept.  I found this for creating a date with no UTC hours from an existing date: `date.setUTCHours(0, 0, 0, 0);//Strip Time`

Comment: You should send it as string. Use the `dateFormat: "d/MM/yyyy" ` option in the datepicker.

Comment: But we don't always want that option - we want the format automatically set based on the local.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that `dateFormat: "d/MM/yyyy"` option of datepicker is what you're looking for.

Otherwise you can use the following code to convert Date object into the required string.

```
date.getDate()+"/"+(date.getMonth()+1)+"/"+date.getFullYear()
```

Both of the options will give you a string with the date, which you can then convert to date object in sql using str_to_date

See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1861519/2652134

Comment: No, `d/m/y` is horrible. Use something that isn't susceptible to language or regional settings, like `yyyymmdd`.

Comment: @Aaron How is this code susceptible to language or regional settings ? It will always return the same format regardless of any settings.

Comment: How did the user being in a different timezone affect the time? And if you pass this string on to other servers, like a database, what is *their* regional / language / dateformat setting? Why use something that's ambiguous when you can use something that's not ambiguous?

Comment: When you can, you should be using a date, and not formatting some string in the first place, of course.

Comment: Exactly what I am trying to do. Make it non ambiguous. Nothing is more non ambiguous than a notation chosen by the developer. Also, note that  he needs representation of a birthday not a point in time.

Comment: I agree with Aaron - we started by passing a string, but the issue was the local can be Italian or American and they use different format's.  By sticking with a Date Object, all that is handled automatically.  So the remaining issue was the time part of the DateObject which is where this question started from.

Comment: `date.getDate()+"/"+(date.getMonth()+1)+"/"+date.getFullYear()` and `dateFormat: "d/MM/yyyy"` will always return the same format XX/YY/ZZZZ. I don't get where italian comes into the scene. You can show it however you want, this is for communicating to the server. Use the `displayFormat` option for that.